# Normalize data between 0 and 95 instead of between 0 and 100

Tags: python, statistics, normalization

I want to normalize the data between 0 and 95 instead of 0 and 100. I am using this formula to normalize between 0 and 100, please let me know how to edit it.

```
def normalization(data):
    return(data - np.min(data)) / (np.max(data) - np.min(data))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply every value by $0.95$. Your original $0$ will stay at $0$; your original $100$ will be reduced to $95$; and the original values in between will be reduced a bit, too.

Comment: you mean (data - np.min(data)) / (np.max(data) - np.min(data))* 0.
95?

Comment: That’s the code, yes (though I didn’t look at your function to make sure it gives values between $0$ and $100$).

Comment: it does and the above solution worked, thank you!